# org.hibernate.console.HibernateConsoleRuntimeException: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

Estoy intentado probar una aplicación con hibernate, pero estoy teniendo bastantes problemas a la hora de configurarlo. De momento he conseguido generar el archivo hibernate.cfg.xml, hibernate.reveng.xml y el objeto de Hibernate Console Configuration.

Cuando intento generar el Hibernate Code me salta la siguiente excepcion:

> org.hibernate.console.HibernateConsoleRuntimeException: Received a
>   NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath is
>   incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class Received
>   a NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath
>   is incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class
>   org.hibernate.console.HibernateConsoleRuntimeException: Received a
>   NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath is
>   incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class Received
>   a NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath
>   is incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap
>   org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap cannot be found by
>   org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_5_1_5.0.1.Final-v20160331-1852-B88
>   org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap cannot be found by
>   org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_5_1_5.0.1.Final-v20160331-1852-B88

Por lo que he investigado se debe a los jars de mi libreria. [Ahora mismo tengo estos:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L82hP.jpg)

Antes tenía mas librerías pero las he elminado, de todos modos os pongo una imagen de las que tenía no sea que [haya borrado alguna que no debía.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeQGC.jpg)

Mi hibernate.cfg.xml esta asi ahora, aunque no estoy seguro de que sea relevante:

```
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="ConexionHibernate">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">hr</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">hr</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltan muchos jars yo tengo estos, de una versión previa de hibenate[image: versión anterior de hibenate]

y estos otros jars son de la ultima version que bajas de la pagina:
[image: Ultima versión de hibenate hasta agosto 2016]

No debiste borrar lo que tenias, sino busca los jars que te puse.

Comment: Gracias! Descargué de nuevo los jars 5.1.1 Final de la pagina de hibernate http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/, añadi absolutamente todos los jars (antes solo habia añadido los de la carpeta "required") y cambié la versión del Hibernate Console a 4.3 y me ha generado el código perfectamente.

Comment: Solo los de la carpeta required son necesarios, los demás son para funcionalidades adicionales muy especificas.
Falta un click en la palomita, por favor.