# Plugin de Hibernate en Eclipse Mars.2 no genera POJO's con Reverse Engineering

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jboss

Bueno, esa es la cuestión. Tengo todo configurado como se supone debería estar configurado, y no me genera nada, ninguna clase o archivo `.hbm.xml` de mapeo. Las librerías que tengo es porque fui agregando por una `NoClassDefFoundError` que no encontraba porque pasaba, y me quedo de esa manera. De la versión `5.2.2.Final` y `5.1.1.Final` tengo todas las librerías, de la `4.3.11.Final` puse solamente la carpeta `required`. Dejo toda la información a continuación:

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="sessionFactory">
  <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">dementoryo</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Universidades</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">Augusto</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">public</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hibernate.reveng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="Alumnos"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="Carrera"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="Detalle_Facultad"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="Docente"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="Facultad"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="Materia"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="Materia_Correlativa"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="Persona"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="Universidad"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Árbol del proyecto

[image: Proyecto Hibernate]

Así me quedó la `Hibernate Console Configuration`

[image: Hibernate Console Configuration]

Y así el Code Generator

[image: Hibernate Code Generator]

No me genera ningún error, ni ninguna advertencia de ningún tipo. No se por donde seguir buscando cual puede ser el error.

Por favor, les agradecería cualquier ayuda, es para una prueba de concepto para una oportunidad de trabajo y necesito solucionarlo.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Revisa este link http://es.wikihow.com/generar-clases-POJO-y-mapeos-de-XML-con-Hibernate-a-partir-de-bases-de-datos

Comment: Como especifico arriba, los pasos de la guía ya los he hecho varias veces, incluso he hecho otros pasos distintos también y tampoco funciona.

Comment: He revisado de nuevo todo lo que expones y creo que no tienes los jars adecuados, aparte de que ya deberías migrar a eclipse neón, mira este link: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20571/org-hibernate-console-hibernateconsoleruntimeexception-noclassdeffounderror/20590

Comment: Ya trate de importar todas las librerías que decía ese post... lo tome como guía antes de postear, al igual que otro post que encontré, pero tampoco me funciono. Son los únicos 2 post que encontré sobre el tema pero incluso haciendo los cambios que indicaban tampoco me funciona.

Comment: Nunca he hecho eso con hibernate, pero como no te queda, he revisado un poco el tema y encontré esta pagina http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#download_base_project donde si le das en el link que dice 'base Java proyect' te descarga un ejemplo. En ese ejemplo me di cuenta de que tu no tienes el archivo reverse.reveng.xml, deberias revisar ese ejemplo. Otra cosa que se me ocurre es que el pluin de eclipse podría estar obsoleto, ya que las versiones que hay en el marketplace de eclipse no siempre son las ultimas, deberías bajar el plugin de su pagina

Comment: Ok, voy a probar y comento que paso. Muchas gracias por la info